# "android sdk update" command does not seem to cache its downloads

Tags: android, jenkins, android-sdk-tools

I'm using this script to install missing SDK dependencies on my Jenkins slaves (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28777153/112705) for more background why I have to do this):

```
android update sdk --all --no-ui --filter extra-android-m2repository,extra-android-support,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-google-m2repository --proxy-host 127.0.0.1 --proxy-port 8080
```

This has worked great for me for a couple of years, but at some point in the last few months, it seems like the downloads stopped getting cached.  i.e. when running it multiple times, it keeps downloading all the same dependencies again and again, even when those dependencies are already installed (and are visible in the SDK manager UI).

I could have sworn that this command used to only download the SDK dependencies when they were not already installed.  Is this a bug, or am I misusing the command line tool?

I'm using build tools v23.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure this has ever worked — see [Android bug #27988](http://b.android.com/27988) from March 2012, for example.

I still have a bunch of related bugs open from around that time. When I implemented automated SDK/platform/tools installation for the [Android Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin), I wrote code to first check with `android list target` whether something was installed, because I think I couldn't rely on `android update sdk` to do the right thing.